# Xcode suddenly can not get Swift package revision: "Couldn't get revision"

Tags: xcode, swift-package-manager

I opened a project in Xcode that relies on `RxSwift` which is included as a Swift package through the builtin Swift package manager.
It worked fine a couple of week ago when I created the project.

Now all of a sudden, when trying to build and run my project, I get an error message about that Swift package:

`Couldn’t get revision ‘6.5.0^{commit}’`

I tried a clean of the build folder, but would still get the same error.

My internet connection is working fine, so it's not a network issue.

I am also surprised that Xcode would try to get the revision again since no update of the package in question, **RxSwift** was released between the time building last worked fine and today. So I would assume that whatever is cached locally should still be there and functional.

So far I could not find any other reports about this error message.

Answer (score 23):

Apparently, something was wrong with the package cache.

An update of Xcode or a cleaning tool I run on my Mac which deletes some caches might have confused Xcode's package cache.

In Xcode, click **File > Packages -> Reset Package Caches** from the menu and then build again.
If that does not do it, first try to restart Xcode and then also try cleaning the build folder as well and try again.

Comment: For anyone else who was lost. The menu is File > Packages -> Reset Package Caches

Comment: After doing this, I also had to restart Xcode (14.0) to get the error to go away.

Comment: Don't need to restart XCode (14.0) beta 5. Just close and re-open the project.

Answer (score 2):

If this issue persists after resetting package caches.

Run the following commands

```
rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/org.swift.swiftpm
rm -rf ~/Library/org.swift.swiftpm
```

Answer (score 1):

For me deleting the `.build` directory in the project directory worked but that's more likely what Xcode actually does anyway with `Reset Package Caches`.